# IIS Vertical Scalability with Multiple App Pools

Tags: iis, scaling, application-pool

In my company, there is an ASP.NET Core application that is being used today but will retire in a year. The application started having huge amount of concurrent users so we need to scale the application without too much investment in it since we will retire it in a year. So we don't want to use a load balancer on a project that will retire in a year at this point.

As a quick fix, without using a load balancer, we are considering using IIS's multiple application pool strategy to handle concurrent requests by vertical scaling the application machine. (increasing RAM, CPU, etc.)

The app can use shared cookies (using ASP.NET Core's DataProtection where key management is stored in the database) so spawning App Pools won't break the cookie authentication the app uses.

Is this feasible? Will having multiple App Pools help connections not to timeout? (We are upgrading the server with 32 core Xeon 2.9 GHz CPU and 512 GB RAM) We don't mind down time if there is a failure with the single server, we are only looking to handle concurrent requests till the end of the year at this point.

Comment: This is the decade old web garden feature of IIS (introduced in IIS 6). As you are happy to accept all its drawbacks as you stated in the question, the answer is also obvious that you will get what you wanted.

Comment: About setting connection timeout on IIS you can refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/sitedefaults/limits#how-to-configure-the-default-connection-limit-options-for-a-server. Application Pool Timeout: http://community.akumina.com/knowledge-base/setting-the-application-pool-timeout/